# Sending serial command to trigger scanner Honeywell 1900

Tags: c#, serial-port

The problem is, that I can trigger scanner using Serial Port software "Hercules" sending command `<SYN>T<CR><LF>`, in datasheet is said to use command `[SYN]T[CR]` to trigger scanner, but I cant trigger it (both commands) using my serial port comunication bellow. 
I get input when use scanner manually but can't trigger it... What is a problem?
(The port is virtual)

```
private static SerialPort port;
private static bool _continue = false;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    port = new SerialPort();
    port.PortName = "COM8";
    port.BaudRate = 115200;
    port.Parity = Parity.None;
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    port.RtsEnable = true;
    port.DtrEnable = true;
    port.ReadTimeout = 500;
    port.WriteTimeout = 500;
    port.Open();

    _continue = true;
    Thread thr = new Thread(SerialPortProgram);
    thr.Start();

}


private static void SerialPortProgram()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Writing to port: <SYN>T<CR><LF>");
    string command = "<SYN>T<CR><LF>";
    port.WriteLine(command);

     while (_continue)
    {
        try
        {
           string input = port.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Input is - " + input);

        }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? (Empty catch blocks are a really bad code smell. I guess your actual code has at least some logging there?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python barcode scanner serial trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50807334/9014308) is an article that I answered similar Python question.

The contents are shown below.

This happens because you coded the abstract expression written in the document as raw output data.

The document represents 3 bytes of data transmission.

'SYN' and 'CR' are the following hexadecimal numbers.

'SYN' = \x16

'CR' = \x0d or escape sequence \r

'T' is an ordinary ASCII character.

Whitespace and < > [ ] { } are used to delimit the data in the document, not the data to send.

And, even you need to command prefix it.

Also use `Write` instead of `WriteLine` as written by @Turbofant.

You should write like this. Please try it.

```
string command = "\x16M\x0d\x16T\x0d";
port.Write(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is, that you are sending the wrong command string.
The `<Syn>`, `<CR>` and `<LF`> stands for the special, non printable ascii characters synchronous idle, Carriage return and line feed.
You need to encode them correctly in the string

Try sending:

```
string command = "\x16t\r\n";
port.Write(command);
```

`\x16`is `<Syn>` (Because Syn is ascii character 0x16, or 22 in decimal  )

`\r` is `<CR>`

`\n` is `<LN>`

And use `port.Write` instead of `port.WriteLine`, because WriteLine automatically adds the `\r\n` at the end of the string.

Comment: To extend the answer: for other control code names, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes